# AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type

Tags: api, dynamic, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman

I am trying to setup postman for Dynamic retail POS API and getting below error when getting the token

adding to this, i have done all settings in the azure app registration
[click the screen shot for reference]

Please can anyone help me on this issue

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue is coming due to header value being set incorrectly. Try adding the header:

```
Origin: http://localhost
```

Comment: Hi Srinath thanks for the reply and I tried with adding origin in the header and getting the same error